# Chain of [key1, value1, key2, value2, ...] to object

Tags: javascript

I am a bit stuck in finding a simple and elegant way to convert an Array like

```
const array = ["k1", "v1", "k2", "v2"]
```

to an object

```
const obj = {"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}
```

Just looking for inspirations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the good-old `for-loop` ?

To recap the proposed solutions

#### for-loop (clean & readable)

```
const obj = {}
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
  obj[array[i]] = array[i + 1]
}
```

#### Array.reduce (oneliner, but a bit cryptic)

```
const obj = array.reduce((acc, curval, idx, arr) => (idx % 2) == 0 ? 
                             (acc[curval] = arr[idx+1], acc) : acc, {});
```

#### _.chunk + Object.fromEntries

I like this solution the most, but it has `lodash` as dependency.
Would be cool if ES could implement it natively `array.chunk(2)`

```
Object.fromEntries(_.chunk(array))
```

Comment: Seems like you are not as stuck as you said. It only took 3 minutes to come up with the obvious answer.

Comment: `i = i + 2` is the same as `i += 2`.

Answer (score 5):

A bit long to really be called a one-liner but if you can find a nice way to chunk the array into pairs then you can just give that to `Object.fromEntries`. Something like lodash's `_.chunk` would make this look a lot better but barring that:

```js
const array = ["k1", "v1", "k2", "v2"]

const obj = Object.fromEntries(Array.from({length: array.length / 2}, (_, i) => array.slice(i, i+2)))
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: `Object.fromEntries` nice! indeed with `_.chunk` its a nice one-liner

Comment: How would chunk apply to an array where prop names and values alternate?

Comment: @danh If names and values alternate in an array, then chunking that array into groups of size 2 gives you exactly the name/value pairs that `Object.fromEntries` is expecting. So then this could just be `Object.fromEntries(_.chunk(array, 2))`.

Answer (score 3):

With  [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const array = ["k1", "v1", "k2", "v2"];
var newarr = array.reduce((acc, curval, idx, arr) => (idx % 2) == 0 ? 
                             (acc[curval] = arr[idx+1], acc) : acc, {});

console.log(newarr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with the code below:

```js
const array = ["k1", "v1", "k2", "v2"];
let obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i+=2) {
  obj[array[i]] = array[i+1];
}

console.log("Array: "+array);
console.log("\nObject: "+array);
console.log("    k1: "+obj["k1"]);
console.log("    k2: "+obj.k2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so elegant, but might lead for farther thoughts:

Using `map`, `reduce`, and `lodash merging`:

```
let array = ["a1", "b1", "a2", "b2"];

array = array.map((e,i)=>{
    let newobj={};
    newobj[e]=array[i+1];
    return i%2===0?newobj:{}
});

array.reduce((v1,v2)=>_.merge(v1, v2));
```

(Assuming an even number of elements in `array`)

Answer (score 0):

Using a function like chunk, but with pure Js:

```js
const array = ["k1", "v1", "k2", "v2"]
function chunks(arr, size = 2) {
  return arr.map((x, i) => i % size == 0 && arr.slice(i, i + size)).filter(x => x)
}
console.log(Object.fromEntries(chunks(array)))
```

And this one is using `flatMap()`:

```js
const array2 = ["k1", "v1", "k2", "v2"]

const pairs = (arr)=>{return arr.flatMap((_, i, a) => i % 2 ? [] : [a.slice(i, i + 2)])}
console.log(Object.fromEntries(pairs(array2)))
```